# Sorting a vector of object pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, vector

I'm writing a GradeBook class with a vector of pointers to StudentInfo class objects `std::vector <StudentInfo*> students;` and I would like to sort it using the `<algorithm>` sort function and evaluating each object by its string data member StudentID. From other posts here on stack overflow, I feel like I got the gist of what I need to do.
First I overloaded the operator< in StudentInfo:

```
bool StudentInfo::operator<(const StudentInfo & right) const
{
    return (this->getStudentID() < right.getStudentID());
}
```

This seems to work correctly.
Then I defined a comparison function in my GradeBook class:

```
bool GradeBook::CompareStudents(const StudentInfo* left, const StudentInfo* right) const
{
    return (*left < *right);
}
```

Again this seems to work fine when I try it independently.
What seems to throw me is when I then try to use the sort function with the CompareStudents function as a third argument to tell it to how to compare the pointers to objects (using the StudentID data member).

```
sort(students.begin(), students.end(), CompareStudents);
```

I've found several examples on stack overflow and elsewhere that seem similar, but I must be doing something wrong, because I keep getting errors:

```
1) 'GradeBook::CompareStudents': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
2) 'sort': no matching overloaded function found
3) 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
```

If I leave off the CompareStudents part and just write `sort(students.begin(), students.end())` it runs okay, but is just comparing pointers which is not the behavior I want.

I'm running Visual Studio Community 2015, if that matters. If this is confusing I can post my whole .h and .cpp files.

Comment: Is `GradeBook::CompareStudents` a `static` member function? If not then you need an *object* to call it on (or make it `static`). Otherwise, have you tried doing what the error messages tells you to do? I.e. use the address-of operator?

Comment: Why not drop the function and use a lambda?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay. I tried making it static and it worked! I'm not sure I understand why though. CompareStudents is in my GradeBook class and it is being called on StudentInfo objects from the vector. Making it static means that if I create several different GradeBook objects they share one copy of the function, but this is unrelated to the StudentInfo class isn't it?

Comment: @PaulRooney I hope to learn lambdas at some point, but I'm still fairly new to c++ so I don't think I'm quite there. A function was much easier for my brain to grasp at this point.

Comment: Non-static member functions needs an *object* to be called on, the object that becomes the `this` pointer. The `sort` function doesn't know anything about your objects, it can't just randomly pick any object and attempt to call the member function on that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The function doesn't need to be in a class at all. it can be `bool CompareStudents(const StudentInfo* left, const StudentInfo* right){...}` and function fine

Comment: @Caleth No it doesn't *need* to be, but it's depending on the design. If the `sort` function is called from within a `GradeBook` member function and the comparison function should never be used from outside the `GradeBook` class, it makes sense that the function is a private (static) member function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it doesn't use *anything* from GradeBook, it makes sense to be a free function

Comment: Perhaps I should have specified that I'm actually using the sort function in a GradeBook member function SortStudents? `void GradeBook::SortStudents() { sort(students.begin(), students.end(), CompareStudents); }` I thought this made sense structurally, and then it would be automatically running on that instance of the GradeBook.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That said, after a night's rest I can see how declaring the CompareStudents function static and/or outside the class would work fine since it is not specific to any one GradeBook class object. Anyways I think I can consider this question answered, but I can't mark your comment as the answer to close this since it wasn't created as an answer. Thanks for your help though.